# Incorporating repeated user input to control while loop

Tags: python, arduino, servo

I am new to programming and am using Python/pyfirmata to control a little servo motor via my arduino.  I have the motor working as I want it to: it spins x degrees every 3 seconds. The problem is that I'd like it to do so continuously until user input tells it to stop.

The code below will continuously ask for user input, which (if 1+ENTER is pressed) causes the motor to turn 3 times before asking for user input again. I can't figure out a way to get the motor running through those positions continuously while simultaneously being able to take user input to stop the motor.

Said another way, this is what I want to be able to do:
Motor is off and user input is requested.
 User presses 1+ENTER and motor starts cycling through positions. If user presses 2+ENTER, motor stops.  If user presses 1+ENTER again, motor starts cycling again. Seems simple, hopefully it is!

My current code:

```
from pyfirmata import SERVO
from pyfirmata import Arduino

board = Arduino("COM4")
board.digital[10].mode = SERVO
servo1 = board.get_pin('d:10:0')

while True:
  user_control = input('Enter 1 to start motor and 2 to stop motor \n')
  if user_control == '1':
    servo1.write(45)
    time.sleep(3)
    servo1.write(90)
    time.sleep(3)
    servo1.write(180)
    time.sleep(3)
  elif user_control == '2':
    servo1.write(45)
    print('motor paused')
```

Comment: You should probably look into [Threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input

Comment: You'll need some time to digest it, but I think you'll find everything you need in it: [How to control a Thread via input()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52356579/9059420)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the input.  I have this working the way I want now.  In the end I created a thread to run the `user_input` function and `threading.Timer` to cause it to loop so that new input could be given every 1 second.  The output from that thread sets a pin value on the arduino which determines whether the `while loop` controlling the motor will run, which turns the motor. Thanks again!  My code is below.

```
from pyfirmata import SERVO
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import threading
import time

board = Arduino("COM4")
board.digital[10].mode = SERVO
servo1 = board.get_pin('d:10:o')
LED = board.get_pin('d:8:o')
servo1.write(15)


def user_input():
    userinput = input('Press 1 or 2\n')
    if userinput == '1':
        return board.digital[7].write(1)
    elif userinput == '2':
        return board.digital[7].write(0)
    elif userinput != "1" or "2":
        input('Press 1 or 2\n')

t1 = threading.Thread(user_input())
threading.Timer(1,user_input).start()

def autorun():
    while board.digital[7].read() == 1:
        servo1.write(45)
        time.sleep(2)
        servo1.write(90)
        time.sleep(2)
        servo1.write(180)
        time.sleep(2)
    if board.digital[7].read() == 0:
        print('automatic run stopped')

autorun()
```